# JDBC class not found on other machine

Tags: java, jdbc, classnotfound

I'm launching a restlet webservice that connects to PostgreSQL. It works fine from Netbeans. 
I've moved jar file and lib directory with all external jars to random location and launched it from command line: it works fine.

The problem is when I move those files to other machine and launch the jar from there. I recieve `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.postgresql.Driver` on `Class.forName()`.

I looked into the manifest: Class-Path: ... *lib/postgresql.jdbc.jar* ... Seems ok. It should be, cause I've tested it with the jdbc file in */lib* and without it (ClassNotFound means he is searching in the lib directory)

So now: why he cannot find class definition on other machine (Debian) when everything is in place, and he has got correct manifest and all jars?

==================================================================================

Just found the solution while starting minecraft server and reading why I had error on that.

The problem was Java. On Debian there are 2 version of Java: 1.5 and 1.7. By default all commands where executed by 1.5 and when I've launched my jar from 1.7 everything wokrs fine.

Comment: Is it in /lib on the computer or /lib in the jar?

Comment: /lib on the computer, and lib is next to main jar

Comment: Sounds like it should work. In the past, long ago, I found a way using the ClassLoader (I think) to print out the classpath from within a commandline Java program. That would help you figure this out.